# Are all real forms of an algebraic Lie algebra algebraic?

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

I could not find any satisfactory answer online so I ask it here.
The problem is the following:

I have a linear complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ which is algebraic $\textit{i.e.}$ the Lie algebra of a complex linear algebraic group $\mathbb{G}(\mathbb{C})$. Are necessarily all real forms of $\mathfrak{g}$ also algebraic (the Lie algebra of a real algebraic group)?
In my case $\mathfrak{g}$ is algebraic because it is semisimple but I'm not sure that this information is relevant for the question.

Thank you!

Comment: Semisimple Lie algebras over a field of characteristic zero are algebraic, because $Der(L)=ad(L)\cong L$ is algebraic? $Der(L)$ is always algebraic.

Comment: I am still reading the proof of the result you mentionned but that would mean that all connected linear semisimple real Lie groups are algebraic (and not only isomorphic to an algebraic group)?(i would use Lie 3rd theorem to prove it)

Comment: I guess my question is : if $\mathfrak{g}$ is an algebraic subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{h}$ a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_m(\mathbb{R})$ is $\mathfrak{h}$ also algebraic?

Comment: @WrabbitW it depends what you mean by the vague "algebraic" (your language melting algebraic groups and groups of real points of algebraic groups is prone to confusion). For instance, $PSL_2(\mathbf{R}):=SL_2(\mathbf{R})/\{\pm I\}$ is not isomorphic to the group of real points of a real algebraic group.

Comment: @YCor Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I have in mind the naïve definition of algebraic group : defined by polynomials equalities. So when I say that $\mathfrak{g}\leq\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is algebraic I mean that there is a subgroup $G$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ defined by polynomials equalities (I call such groups linear/affine algebraic groups) whose Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{g}$. I guess that in that sense $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not a linear algebraic group? Actually I don't see how a quotient could be algebraic with this definition?

Comment: $PSL_2(\mathbf{C})$ is algebraic in this definition. And so is $PGL_2(\mathbf{R})$, but not its subgroup of index two $PSL_2(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: How do you see $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $PGL_2(\mathbb{R})$ as matrix group? I cannot get how to avoid the equivalence class definition. Also do you have any reference text for real points of algebraic groups? and finally with this definition is my question in the second comment true?

Comment: I have no reference, the naive definition is not a good theory. There are standard reference (Borel/Springer) on linear algebraic groups.

Comment: $PGL_2$ can be viewed through its 3-dimensional representation, say, the determinant 1 stabilizer of the quadratic form $X^2+Y^2-Z^2$.

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question: every real semisimple Lie algebra is the Lie algebra of some real linear algebraic group.

Comment: Ok I'll look into it. The problem is that in Model theory you want to look at definitions as simple as you can ie zeros of polynomials and cannot really talk about schemes and such things. Anyway thank you for the help I would apreciate a reference for the last result you mentionned.

Comment: Actually I am not sure that it answered my question because you said "some" algebraic group but I would like to know if you can force this group to live in the same $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ as the Lie algebra. Something like my comment question.